# System year YYYY plus coulmn's value MMDD insert into Database as 'dd-MMM-yyyy' in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, oracle11g

I am to read text file where a column of purchase date with format MMDD is available. It is being read and inserted all records successfully. But now i want to insert "system year" with "purchase date" as "dd-MMM-yyyy" into date column of database. Example: If purchase date is "0812" and System Year is '19', then date will be "12-AUG-19". How can i do this ?

Comment: Can you provide examples of what you have tried and where exactly your error is coming from? We can't really help otherwise, there are some good examples of how to work with dates on the https://learn.microsoft.com website

Answer (score 1):

As of Oracle, you'd apply a few *transformations*:

- concatenate value you have (0812) with this year (which is what `extract` does)
- apply `to_date` to it, with appropriate format mask (`mmddyyyy`)
- apply `to_char` to that value, with desired/final format mask (`dd-mon-yyyy`)

Something like this:

```
SQL> select to_char(to_date('0812' || extract(year from sysdate), 'mmddyyyy'), 'dd-mon-yyyy') result from dual;
                             ----
                             this is what you have, MMDD

RESULT
-----------
12-aug-2019

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for **C# code** then, you can first `Parse`, then create a required `DateTime` and, finally, format the `DateTime`:

```
  string source = @"0812";
  int SystemYear = 19;

  // Parsed date, note, that year is DateTime.Now.Year, not required SystemYear
  DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(source, "MMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

  date = new DateTime(
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.ToFourDigitYear(SystemYear), // SystemYear
    date.Month,                                                        // same Month
    date.Day);                                                         // same Day

  // "12-AUG-19"
  string result = date.ToString("dd'-'MMM'-'yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToUpper();
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what is data format in your tables column. If it's type of Date, then showing `12-AUG-19` is just a display issue, and has nothing to do with inserting. If it's varchar column, then you first need to read your date from source f.e.:

```
var source = "0812";
source += DateTime.Now.Year;
Console.WriteLine(source);
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(source, "MMddyyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(date);
```

So now you have date as `DateTime` object, and it depends on your DB structure if you will post it as `string` to DB, or as proper Date column.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you can insert a date using many different formats, so it would not be necessary to have the format 'DD-mon-YY' to insert the value in a date column.
The TO_DATE function uses the current year value by default to complete the format:

```
SQL> SELECT TO_DATE('0812', 'MMDD')from dual;

TO_DATE('0812','M
-----------------
12/08/19 00:00:00
```

And this is an example of what I mean:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE DATE_SAMPLE ( DATE_VALUE DATE);

Table DATE_SAMPLE creado.

SQL> INSERT INTO DATE_SAMPLE SELECT TO_DATE('0812', 'MMDD')from dual;
1 fila insertadas.

SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE_VALUE, 'DD-mon-YY') from DATE_SAMPLE;

TO_CHAR(DATE_VALUE,'DD-MON-YY')                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
12-ago-19
```

You can insert a date specifying the format in the TO_DATE function and read it in the desired format using the TO_CHAR function.

[TO_DATE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions219.htm#SQLRF06132)

[TO_CHAR](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions216.htm#SQLRF06129)